# How to override max-width for specific div?

Tags: css

I am searching for the following solution. In my CSS I have the following:

```
img, a img { 
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle; 
}
```

This code is necessary for my WordPress theme and responsive web design. Now I want to override `max-width` property to `auto`. When I do this, it doesn't override:

```
#pixel-perfect img {
    max-width: auto !important;
    position: absolute;
    margin: -200px 0 0 -140px;
    z-index: -9999;
}
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Are you just looking to *unset* the `max-width` property? If so, try:

```
#pixel-perfect img {
    max-width: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because `a img` is more specific than `#pixel-perfect img`. Element selector is more specific than id selector (So in this example you have 2 elements vs 1element and 1 id).

In order to fix it, you'd have to add an element to your declaration, for example:

```
a#pixel-perfect img {
    max-width: auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that your `#pixel-perfect img` CSS declaration is BELOW the `img, a img` declaration, otherwise it will get overwritten.

```
#pixel-perfect img {
    max-width: none;
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    margin: -200px 0 0 -140px;
    z-index: -9999;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
max-width: auto !important;
```

auto in max-width is not a valid property. You should replace it with

```
max-width: none !important;
```